# Bind rows of dataframes from one list to dataframes in another list

Tags: r, list

Given 2 lists of dataframes of the same length with the same column names, what is the correct way to bind the rows from each dataframe in one list to each dataframe in the other list?

Some data:

```
list1 <- data.frame("x" = c(1,2), "z" = c(2,3), "y" = c(3,4))
list2 <- data.frame("x" =c(1,2), "z" = c(2,3), "y" = c(3,4))
Mylist1 <- list(list1, list2)   

list1 <- data.frame("x" = c(5,6,7), "z" = c(7,8,9), "y" = c(10,11,12))
list2 <- data.frame("x" = c(25,26,27), "z" = c(27,28,29), "y" = c(210,211,212))
Mylist2 <- list(list1, list2)
```

current data:

```
> Mylist1
[[1]]
  x z y
 1 2 3
 2 3 4

[[2]]
  x z y
 1 2 3
 2 3 4

> Mylist2
[[1]]
  x z  y
 5 7 10
 6 8 11
 7 9 12

[[2]]
   x  z   y
 25 27 210
 26 28 211
 27 29 212
```

Desired output:

```
> MyNewList
    [[1]]
      x z y
      1 2 3
      2 3 4
      5 7 10
      6 8 11
      7 9 12
    [[2]]
      x z y
      1 2 3
      2 3 4
      25 27 210
      26 28 211
      27 29 212
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` here and `rbind` the two list

```
Map(rbind, Mylist1, Mylist2)


#[[1]]
#  x z  y
#1 1 2  3
#2 2 3  4
#3 5 7 10
#4 6 8 11
#5 7 9 12

#[[2]]
#   x  z   y
#1  1  2   3
#2  2  3   4
#3 25 27 210
#4 26 28 211
#5 27 29 212
```

This is also similar to

```
mapply(rbind, Mylist1, Mylist2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

and

```
purrr::map2(Mylist1, Mylist2, rbind)
```